# Authenticated user misusing firebase databse to increase points

Tags: android, firebase

I have made an android app and using Firebase realtime database as backend. In the app i have some In-App purchase products too. These products are abount buying points(such as 150 points, 1000 points etc.). The problem is right now i am seeing that some users increasing huge amount of points to their profile. For the sake of relatime view of firebase database i am seeing that their points increasing like 50k, 100k. But i don't have any In-App purchase product with this huge amount. I am tired of disabling their account & can't find a way to prevent it.

I know some app that are used to hack points/coins like Freedom APK and some other. But these apps require the device to be rooted. So on App launch i checked whether the device is rooted or not. Right now rooted device are not allowed to use my app. Still they are hacking points.

I am using following database rules

```
{
   "rules": {
     "Users": {
      "$userID": {
         ".write": "auth != null",
           ".read": "auth != null"
       }
     }
   }
}
```

And database structure is:

```
Users-
    uId:
       userEmail
       userName
       userPoints
```

The workflow of valid point increase is:

```
User buy a In-App product --> User points increase as per the product value

User watch a rewarded video ad --> User points increase by +8
```

I want to prevent these hackers to generating points.

Comment: what is the expectation? are they not allowed to buy over a certain limit? what is the workflow? where is the code from where you increase the points? how is it access from the app?

Comment: my expectation is to prevent those users who are hacking the points. I edited the workflow of point incresement please check. And point update code is simply the way we set value to firebase realtime databse. @AbhirojPanwar

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert with android and realtime database but the problem is that the user have write access to the database.

I do not know how but they somehow can manipulate the data which is sent to your database.

You need to validate the data before it is written to your database.

You could do some validation with security rules but in my opinion the easiest way is to use callable cloud functions to validate your data and revoke the write access to your database.

If the user buys points they should call a cloud function which verifies if the data is valid. If the data is valid the cloud function updates the database. This way the user can not manipulate their points.

For my online shop i use cloud functions to verify the cart content on checkout and the users can not directly write to the database.

You should do something similar.

**Edit:**

Here you could find an introduction to cloud functions.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

And here you could find some information about callable cloud function which i recommend. With a callable function you can invoke the backend function directly from your code without an API call.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Can you please tell me the workflow to achieve that?

Comment: I agree with Sebe. Since your users have access to write they can change the values to whatever they want as long as they authenticate.

Comment: How do you collect the payment? Personally, i do not trust payments which are confirmed on the client side. But it could looks something like this. Payment confirmed >> cloud function checks if payment valid >> cloud function writes updated points to database.